# How to reorder columns in ascending or descending fashion when they are dynamic

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a Kusto function that returns a result set which has dates formatted as "yyyy-MM-dd" as the column names and then certain value as the cell values. Example:

[image]

I want the result set to be ordered by date. Is there a way to do this? As per project-reorder documentation, I tried to say project_reorder yyyy-mm-dd desc but that does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `project-reorder` should work.

for example:

```
print d = dynamic({"2020-06-01":1, "2020-05-01":2, "2019-03-01":3, "2019-06-01":4})
| evaluate bag_unpack(d)
| project-reorder ['20*'] asc
```

-->

```
2019-03-01  2019-06-01  2020-05-01  2020-06-01
3           4           2           1
```